# Is it possible to make Tap Gesture Recognizer work if UIImageView it's connected to is under UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Please take a look on a screenshot [image: below]

I have a UIImageView with Tap Gesture Recognizer connected to it ("Mans body image view"). When I tap this UIImage I want it to call a keyboard with colors so I can change skin color of this mans figure.

For now it does not work because on top of Mans body image view I have 4 scroll views which are responsible for hair, facial hair and clothing (tops and bottoms).

Is there any way I can make Tap Gesture Recognizer (under scroll views) to react on my taps?

Thank you

Comment: Try using UIGestureRecognizer's delegate https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate and implement its methods so that your scroll views' gesture recognizers don't block your tap gesture recognizer. Unfortunately, you might have to those scroll views instances of a custom UIScrollView subclass in order to implement these methods for scroll views recognizers. That's because only UIScrollView can be the delegate of its gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `UIScrollView subclass` and implement

```
func gesture​Recognizer(UIGesture​Recognizer, should​Recognize​Simultaneously​With:​ UIGesture​Recognizer)
```

*Asks the delegate if two gesture recognizers should be allowed to recognize gestures simultaneously.*

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

or use horizontal UICollectionView instead and implement delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I would prefer UICollectionView, it is created for displaying a collection of images, it has proper methods to handle tap gesture. It's the best option if you don't want to recreate a bicycle ;) Plus I advise you to read the documentation and compare the APIs of scrollview and collection view (which inherits from scrollview), you'll understand the difference and will be prepared for this kind of decisions in the future!

Comment: As I understand UIImageView with Tap gesture recognizer still will be under the UICollectionView, no?

Comment: No, UICollectionView has this out of the box with delegate method didSelectItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Playing with UICollectionView now. More questions are coming :)